# My feature images are showing up twice on the preview page

Tags: images

I own the lowly knitting blog www.oftengrumpy.com. I am having a problem with my feature photos showing up twice on the preview page that shows snippets of my posts (not the individual post pages themselves) You can see the problem here: http://oftengrumpy.com/category/knitting-3/

I know I have image size issues and I'll get to that later. I just really want to figure out how to make the duplicate photos go away.

Also, when viewed in firefox specifically, the top of the duplicate photos is displayed way off to the right behind my widgets. I haven't found a solutions that has corrected the problem yet.

I am NOT putting the image in the body of my post in addition to setting it as the feature photo. I have also already tried using the regenerate thumbnails plugin.

Comment: Since WP is so flexible anyone can write code for it. So it's pretty hard to figure out your issue not knowing the code that displays that page. It would be great if you could provide us with the page template code.It's likely that's in a category.php or archive.php file. But that can also change from theme to them. Also, different themes have different ways to set the "featured image". So, maybe a screenshot of the edit page would help, or the theme name. The more information you provide, the easier it is for someone here to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you given like

```
echo the_post_thumbnail($post_id);
```

No need of giving echo if we are using **the_post_thumbnail()**.It by default echoing the result.So here, it will display the image twice.
If we use   get_the_post_thumbnail(),   then **echo** is needed.

So use either

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
```

or

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

Try this..